# How to properly scope validator function in parent class for use in child class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to use validators, but I'm having a mysterious issue with using validators in a parent/child class.

Right now I've created a base class for all media in my project; all media in this model need a name and a thumbnail:

```
class BaseMedia(BaseModel):
    def validate_thumbnail(image_obj):
        validate_image_file_extension(image_obj)
        dimensions = [image_obj.width, image_obj.height]
        if dimensions[0] != 400 or dimensions[1] != 400:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Thumbnail dimensions must be 400 x 400; uploaded image is %s x %s"
                % (dimensions[0], dimensions[1])
            )

    media_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=25, verbose_name="Title (25 char)", null=True
    )
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        verbose_name="Thumbnail (400 x 400 px)",
        upload_to="microscopy/images/thumbnails",
        validators=([validate_thumbnail],),
    )
```

and then I have a child class that inherits and implement the core media itself; for example:

```
class MicroscopyMedia(BaseMedia):
    def validate_image(image_obj):
        validate_image_file_extension(image_obj)
        dimensions = [image_obj.width, image_obj.height]
        if dimensions[0] != 1920 or dimensions[1] != 1070:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Image dimensions must be 1920 x 1070; uploaded image is %s x %s"
                % (dimensions[0], dimensions[1])
            )

    media = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        verbose_name="Media (1920 x 1070 px)",
        blank=True,
        upload_to="microscopy/images",
        validators=[validate_image],
    )
```

The idea being that all models will need a thumbnail, but within the child class I have a specific validator for each individual media type.

However, when I try to make this migration, I get an error:

```
(env) PS D:\Projects\django-cms\projects\cms> python .\manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
microscopy.BaseMedia.thumbnail: (fields.E008) All 'validators' must be callable.
        HINT: validators[0] ([<function BaseMedia.validate_thumbnail at 0x000001D3193C8A60>]) isn't a function or instance of a validator class.
```

There seems to be a scoping issue at play here.  As defined, `validate_thumbnail()` is just a regular function within the scope of `BaseMedia`, and isn't available to `MicroscopyMedia`.  However, I can't make it a member function either, since I can't pass the `self` parameter.

How should I define this validator function in the parent class so that when the child class calls it, it's a valid function call?

Comment: Within the class you wrote `def validate_thumbnail(image_obj):` with no `@staticmethod` decorator. Did you maybe want to include a `self` parameter in there?

Comment: I don't think so?  Do validators need to be standalone functions that don't take `self` as an argument?  I've tried both adding `self` and adding `@staticmethod` and both cause a SystemCheckError when I'm trying to migrate

Comment: Ok. I don't write django validators, myself. The code in the OP just looks weird, like `def foo():` was accidentally moved from top-level module scope so it's down within a `class` definition. // When I read about [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/validators) the examples seem pretty clear about putting the `def` up at module scope, and not down within the class. We **refer** to it within the class, but we **define** it up top.

Comment: I totally agree, and that was my preferred way to do it -- but when I do that, I get `AttributeError: type object 'BaseMedia' has no attribute 'validate_thumbnail'`, so it seems to expect it to be defined locally (even with a @staticmethod decorator)

Comment: Show the full stack trace in the Question, please -- what did you run and what did you see? If need be, another module can always do `from microscopy import validate_thumbnail`, if it needs that symbol.

Comment: **Typo**: `([validate_thumbnail],)` creates a tuple with a list inside it... Change that to `[validate_thumbnail]`. Also although this works it would be best to simply move the validator out of your model class as a top level function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your code in this way:

```
def validate_thumbnail(image_obj):
    validate_image_file_extension(image_obj)
    ...

class BaseMedia(BaseModel):
    ...
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        ...
        validators=([validate_thumbnail],),
    )
```

Similarly, promote `def validate_image():` so it's up at module scope,
rather than buried down within a `class` definition.